# The equation of the sphere using $(-2,3,4)$ and $(4,1,-5)$ as endpoints of its diameter.

Tags: calculus, geometry

I find the center point $(1,2,-1/2)$ and make an equation like $$(x-1)^2 + (y-2)^2 + 
(z+1/2)^2 = r^2$$

To obtain $r$, I subtract $(-2,3,4)$ and the center line and calculate the length of 
vector $(121/4)^{1/2}$.

Finally, I made an equation $(x-1)^2 + (y-2)^2 + \left(z+1/2\right)^2 = 121/4$. Did I solve 
this problem in the right way?.

$$(x-1)^2 + (y-2)^2 + \left(z+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 = \frac{121}{4}$$

Comment: @ user43836:  I haven't checked all your arithmetic, but the general approach looks right.

Comment: It is right. The result is right.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your approach is correct, as is your final result!

(As for whether solved it the "right way": it's exactly how I would have approached the problem!)

Comment: Looks cool with this new hat. :D

Comment: Hi, dear friend, @B.S.!